How do I replace these deck stairs?
A couple of these deck boards have cracked so I am trying to replace them. I noticed that the previous owner used trex screws on wood so that might have contributed to the boards cracking.
My main issue is I can’t figure out how to remove the railing in order to access the screws that are along the left side basically below the railing. Also, the bottom step has a hole cut through it for the bottom post.  I don’t want to destroy or replace the railing and I can’t see how it’s attached, there’s visible screws for the small 1x1 slats but not connecting to the either end post?




If you go under the deck, you should be able to see the carriage bolts holding the newel posts. Remove these and the whole railing should come out, posts and all.
If you can't find and/or reach the carriage bolts, you can remove the screws holding the treads using a screwdriver extension. I have a set made for electricians that works perfectly for this type of job.
Unless the rails were mortised into the newel post, they should also be somehow attached. Look for hidden screws from the bottom, L-brackets, etc. You might then be able to remove the rails and balusters without disassembling the whole thing.
